# EF Core 1.0 Foreign Key Issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I do not really understand is this EF Core 1.0 bug?

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
public class UserDetail : BaseEntity
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserLanguage> Languages { get; set; }
}

public class UserLanguage : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

In my User table I have 3 users

```
Id          Username
----------- ---------------

1           john
2           doe
3           jack
```

In my UserDetail I have 2 records

```
Id          UserId      Address                                           Country
----------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- ------
1           1           Some Address                                       MY
2           3           NULL                                               SG
```

In my UserLanguage when perform insert

```
INSERT INTO UserLanguage(Name, UserId)
VALUES ('English', 3)
```

it will encounter below error

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UserLanguage_UserDetail_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "Job", table "dbo.UserDetail", column 'Id'.
```

What I do wrong in here? ForeignKey is UserId how come it point to UserDetail column 'Id'

Comment: Are you actually executing the SQL statement you provided (e.g. with ExecuteSqlCommand) or is that just a rough translation of your EF code? It's unlikely to be a bug in EF either way, but if you're executing the SQL you may find better luck with the tags "T-SQL" and "SQL" - this sounds more like a table configuration problem than a code issue.

Comment: Basically I do perform insert using entityframework insertasync then I get that error. Then I write the SQL statement and execute it in the sql ide is also return the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserLanguage> Languages { get; set; }
}
public class UserDetail : BaseEntity
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }        
}

public class UserLanguage : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; } 
}
```

The problem was in the following line of code

```
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public virtual ICollection<UserLanguage> Languages { get; set; }
```

this created a foreign key relation between UserDetail and UserLanguage table while you wanted to create it between User and UserLanguage table.

In your existing schema if you try to insert

```
INSERT INTO UserLanguage(Name, UserId)
VALUES ('English', 1) 
INSERT INTO UserLanguage(Name, UserId)
VALUES ('French', 2)
```

It will succeed as UserDetail have two entries with 1,2 PK while there is no entry with PK 3 in UserDetail.

Answer (score 0):

To your `UserLanguage` class try to add:

```
public virtual UserDetail UserDetail  { get; set; }
```